# Constraint with non Foreign Key join in Django

Tags: sql, django

In my database I have a pair of tables (`tableA` and `tableB`), both of which have foreign keys referencing the same column `ID` in `tableC`. The SQL I was able to use was

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.ID=tableB.ID
WHERE tableB.year=2011
```

The query

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.ID=tableB.ID AND tableB.year=2011
```

Did the same thing

In Django I tried to do this with the code

```
subquery=tableB.objects.filter(year=2011).values_list(id, flat=True)
results=tableA.objects.filter(id__in=list(subquery))
```

as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#in). I know this is a little different because it only returns columns in `tableA`, but I only use those anyway. The Django code seemed slow, I think partly because of the set membership test for every row of `tableA`, which is very large. Is there a way of making this faster in Django without using raw SQL (which I obviously can use if I need to)?

Comment: Likely a stupid question, but what the heck - are you running on a recent build of Django?

Comment: I am using Django 1.3, and not the dev build, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: If you haven't already, jump on the #django channel on irc.freenode.net - there's a fair number of pretty awesome devs on there - pass them the url to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is slow because it is creating a query that probably looks something like

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TableB WHERE year=2011)
```

Like @Udi said, you'd be better off if you could "django"-ize the models by adding the Foreign keys some how.  Otherwise, use the RawSQL.  That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your models are not very "django" friendly.  Are you using one-to-one relationships, and your table pk are the foreign keys?  (If not, post your schema in the question).  Django prefers your table (models) primary keys to be unique auto increment integers and not foreign keys.

django wise this is better:

```python
class TableC(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class TableA(models.Model): 
     tablec = models.OneToOneField(TableC)

class TableB(models.Model): 
     tablec = models.OneToOneField(TableC)
     year = models.IntegerField()
```

Notice all fields have an (implicit) id field which is the primary key for the table. And now execute:

```python
TableA.objects.filter(tablec__tableb__year__exact=2011)
```

You can actually use a foreign key as your primary key:

```python
class TableC(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class TableA(models.Model): 
     tablec = models.OneToOneField(TableC, primary_key=True, db_column='id')

class TableB(models.Model): 
     tablec = models.OneToOneField(TableC, primary_key=True, db_column='id')
     year = models.IntegerField()
```

And execute the same query.  However this might cause you some more problems later ("no warranty").

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would do that, but my models actually come from data from other sources, and I am just using Django as an interface for that data. Plus, I cannot think of any way of making the relationships in the table into one-to-one relationships without denormalizing, which I would prefer not to do.

Comment: I believe you can still do the above using one-to-many and avoid raw sql.  A foreign key - foreign key join across three tables might be still faster in some cases than using a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert `subquery` to a list. If you just did this:

```
results=tableA.objects.filter(id__in=subquery)
```

Django should be clever enough to actually do a subquery, rather than two separate queries.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using a MySQL database, and the documentation page I linked to says that MySQL does not optimize nested queries well and that using two queries would be faster.